# How do I put regex match groups into separate output columns, correctly handling missing/empty values?

Tags: bash, grep, text-processing

if I have the following file:

```
This file has two lines
This file has three lines
This file has four
This file has five lines
```

I would like to grep for `file` and `lines` so that I have the following output:

```
file lines
file lines
file
file lines
```

where if both matches are found per line, print the matches on the same line. If only one has been found, print it, leave a placeholder (null/blank/whatever) and then move onto next line.

I have tried to do this with:

```
grep -oP '(file)|(lines)' example.txt | paste -d ' ' - -
```

but I get:

```
file lines
file lines
file file
lines
```

where because `lines` hasn't been found on the third line, it finds `file` from the next line and puts it on the same output line.

I am basically forcing `paste` to fill slots in the output regardless of what is found on each line.

how can I change this?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe `paste` to be the right tool for the job?

Comment: Not anymore, don't mind how it's done.

Comment: I've edited the title to be less opinionated about the implementation. If I made it less accurate in any way, please let me know or re-edit.

Comment: Make it miles easier by just using text parsing language like perl `perl -ne 'print "$& " while m/file|lines/g;print "\n"' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `file` and `lines` will actually be regular expressions with their own match groups. The following allows any ERE to be used in place:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# replace these with any ERE-compliant regex of your choice
file_re='(file)'    # for instance: file_re='file=([^[:space:]]+)([[:space]]|$)'
lines_re='(lines)'

while IFS= read -r line; do
  # default to a blank placeholder if no matches exist
  file= lines=

  # compare against each regex; if one matches, assign the group contents to a variable
  [[ $line =~ $file_re ]] && file=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  [[ $line =~ $lines_re ]] && lines=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

  # print a line of output if *either* regex matched.
  [[ $file || $lines ]] && printf '%s\t%s\n' "$file" "$lines"

done <"${1:-example.txt}" # with input from $1 if given, or example.txt otherwise
```

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) (*"How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"*) for a description of the technique used here.

---

With your given input, the output is:

```
file    lines
file    lines
file
file    lines
```

Comment: This is perfect and you've correctly assumed what the problem was. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for `s/old/new/` and grep is for `g/re/p`. For any other text manipulation you should be using awk.

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '{f=match($0,/file/,a); f+=match($0,/lines/,b)} f{print a[0], b[0]}' file
file lines
file lines
file
file lines
```

With other awks you'd use substr() to capture the matching strings:

```
$ awk '{f=match($0,/file/); a=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); f+=match($0,/lines/); b=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} f{print a, b}' file
file lines
file lines
file
file lines
```